# Sorting routes in neo4j based on the highest value properties of the nodes in the route

Tags: neo4j

I have a standard query in neo4j to search for all shortest routes between two nodes.

```
MATCH 
     (object:Object { group: "12345" }), 
     (request:Request { group: "12345"}), 
     paths = allShortestPaths((request)-[*..12]->(object)) 
RETURN  
     paths
```

The task is to sort the routes by the highest property value of the nodes in each route..

Let's say the query returns three routes of this type:

```
 [{prop:1},{prop:2},{prop:4}],
 [{prop:1},{prop:2},{prop:3}],    
 [{prop:1},{prop:2},{prop:5}],
```

The task is to return the routes for the highest value of the property "prop" and get the routes in this order:

```
[{prop:1},{prop:2},{prop:3}],    
[{prop:1},{prop:2},{prop:4}],
[{prop:1},{prop:2},{prop:5}],
```

If anyone faced, please give advice on solving the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Managed to solve the problem. Here is a query. Maybe someone will need to sort the routes by relevance.

```
MATCH 
         (object:Object { group: "12345" }), 
         (request:Request { group: "12345"}), 
         paths = allShortestPaths((request)-[*..12]->(object)) 
WITH  
         paths, EXTRACT(x IN nodes(paths) | toInt(x.prop)) AS propsSort
UNWIND  
         propsSort as sort
RETURN  
         paths, max(sort) as sort
ORDER BY 
         sort DESC
```

Answer (score 1):

Based on your answer:

```
MATCH 
         (object:Object { group: "12345" }), 
         (request:Request { group: "12345"}), 
         paths = allShortestPaths((request)-[*..12]->(object)) 
WITH  
         paths, EXTRACT(x IN nodes(paths) | toInt(x.prop)) AS propsSort
RETURN  
         paths, REDUCE(m=propsSort[0], 
                       v in propsSort[1..] |
                       CASE WHEN v>m THEN v ELSE m END
                ) as sort
ORDER BY 
         sort DESC
```

Or you can use the [collection function](https://neo4j-contrib.github.io/neo4j-apoc-procedures/#_collection_functions) `max` from apoc library:

```
apoc.coll.max([0.5,1,2.3])
```